# Building a project with maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to execute a sample application from here: http://www.ixtendo.com/secure-your-jsf-application-with-jaas/#comment-3792. The author says:

> To build the project, you have to install Maven and call mvn clean package.

I have installed Maven in my Ubuntu 12.04. But I am new to Maven and don't know how to build the project with it. Could someone please explain in detail how to build the project with Maven?

Comment: Did you actually try to do what the author said? I.e. `mvn clean package`

Comment: Which Maven tutorial did you find in your online searching and which step of that are you finding difficult or confusing?

Comment: @Stephan no actually not..exactly Where should I write that command ?

Comment: You seem to be in need of an introductory tutorial to maven. there are many good ones on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `mvn clean` will work only if you are executing the command from the context of the application where **pom.xml** is located.

here is a quick tutorial for [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).